# GPIO Python 3 with Relay

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi3, relay

i am testing a relay module with raspberry pi 3 b gpio and i dont understand why the relay go on when the pin state is equal to 0. I have created this simple program that can work only if i set 0 as output. its like the values are reversed.

**This is my simple program**

```
try:
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time
    print("GPIO Loaded")
except RuntimeError:
    print("error with loading GPIO library")
pins = [3,5,7,11,13,15,19,21]
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

for i in pins:
   GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT)
   GPIO.output(i, 0)
   time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an "active low" relay.

Relays were designed like this for [historical reasons](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196139/why-is-designed-active-low).